# ESP32 MQTT event processing

Tags: c, mqtt, esp32

I am trying to use arduino-esp32 methods defined in file mqtt_client.h for my [ESP32/Arduino IDE](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/96822d783f3ab6a56a69b227ba4d1a1a36c66268/tools/sdk/include/esp-mqtt/mqtt_client.h) project :

I am struggling to make an event handler out of this.

I currently have:

```
#include <mqtt_client.h>

void MQTTEvent(esp_mqtt_event_t event) {
  // process event
}

void setup() {
  esp_mqtt_client_config_t mqtt_cfg;
  mqtt_cfg.host = "192.168.0.126";
  mqtt_cfg.port = 1883;
  mqtt_cfg.client_id = "ESP32";
  mqtt_cfg.uri = "HOMEPC";
  mqtt_cfg.event_handle = MQTTEvent;

  esp_mqtt_client_handle_t mqtt_client = esp_mqtt_client_init(&mqtt_cfg);
  esp_mqtt_client_start(mqtt_client);
}

void loop() {

}
```

... but it fails with:

```
*invalid conversion from 'void (*)(esp_mqtt_event_t)' to 'mqtt_event_callback_t {aka int (*)(esp_mqtt_event_t*)}' [-fpermissive]*

on line mqtt_cfg.event_handle = MQTTEvent;
```

I wasn't able to find any example. Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of your event handle is wrong, it should return an `esp_err_t` so instead be:

```
esp_err_t MQTTEvent(esp_mqtt_event_t *event) {
  ...
  return ESP_OK; // you will need to return esp error codes
}
```

See the definition here: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/protocols/mqtt.html#_CPPv419esp_mqtt_event_id_t

Comment: Thank you! It also needed to add pointer to the (esp_mqtt_event_t event) but now it compiles! Thank you!

Comment: @Petr yes, I mixed up `esp_mqtt_event_t` with `esp_mqtt_event_handle__t` with is just a pointer to the former, fixed in answer